# Does Boost::Context work on iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, boost, boost-context

I am trying to build boost::context for an iOS app. I tried following the instructions on boost's site, but I am finding them a little complicated. So I copied the /boost/context directory, and any other header's xcode asked for into my xcode project.

Now, I am trying to figure out which source files I should build.

My choices from the provided source:
    http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/context/src/asm/

Which of these files, if any, are the correct ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Boost::Context works on iOS!

The correct files to compile are

```
jump_arm_aapcs_macho_gas.S
make_arm_aapcs_macho_gas.S
```